# spring boot - integration test autowired interface no such bean found

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5, spring-boot-test

I have a spring-boot app that now needs to support multiple Object stores and selectively use the desired store based on the environment. Essentially what i have done is create an interface that each store repository then implements.

I have simplified the code for the examples.
I have created 2 beans for each store type based on the spring profile determining the env:

```
  @Profile("env1")
  @Bean
  public store1Sdk buildClientStore1() {
     return new store1sdk();
  }

  @Profile("env2")
  @Bean
  public store2Sdk buildClientStore2() {
     return new store2sdk();
  }
```

in the service layer I have autowired the interface and then in the repositories i have used @Profile to specify which instance of the interface to use.

```
public interface ObjectStore {
  String download(String fileObjectKey);
  ...
}

@Service
public class ObjectHandlerService {

  @Autowired
  private ObjectStore objectStore;

  public String getObject(String fileObjectKey) {
    return objectStore.download(fileObjectKey);
  }
  ...
}

@Repository
@Profile("env1")
public class Store1Repository implements ObjectStore {
  @Autowired
  private Store1Sdk store1client;

  public String download(String fileObjectKey) {
    return store1client.getObject(storeName, fileObjectKey);
  }
}
```

When I start the application with the configured "env" this actually runs as expected. however when running the test I get the "no qualifying bean of type ObjectStore. expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate."

```
@ExtendWith({ SpringExtension.class })
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
@ActiveProfiles("env1,test")
public class ComposerServiceTest {
  @Autowired
  private ObjectHandlerService service;

  @Test
  void download_success() {
    String response = service.getObject("testKey");
    ...
  }
}
```

As noted in the @ActiveProfile on the test class there are some other environments e.g. dev,test,prod. I have tried playing around with Component scan, having impl and interface in the same package, etc, to no success. I feel like I am missing something obvious with the test setup. But could be something with my overall application config? my main aim with the solution is to avoid having something a long the lines of

```
    if (store1Sdk != null) {
      store1Sdk.download(fileObjectKey);
    }
    if (store2Sdk != null) {
      store2Sdk.download(fileObjectKey);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `@ActiveProfiles({"env1", "test"})`.

Activate multiple profiles using `@ActiveProfiles` and specify profiles as an array.

Answer (score 0):

this probrom because Store1Repository use `@Profile("env1")`, when you use `@test`,this class not invoke. try delete `@Profile("env1")` of `Store1Repository`.

if you use `@test`, both of `store1Sdk/store2Sdk` don't instanse, try add default `instanse.eg`:

```
@Bean    
public store2Sdk buildClientStoreDefault() {
    return new store2sdk();
}
```

Comment: if you remove the profile annotations from the repository implementations would you not end up with the opposite problem of it trying to instantiate 2 instances of ObjectStore?

Comment: if you use @test,both of store1Sdk/store2Sdk don't instanse, try add default instanse.eg: